# Prevent case-insensitivity change in OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer

Tags: java, owasp, html-sanitizing

I have some XML data in my request as:

```
<transaction
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:Object">
    <transactionNum xsi:type="xsd:long">4</transactionNum>
    <operations xsi:type="xsd:List">
        <elem xsi:type="xsd:Object">
            <criteria xsi:type="xsd:Object">
                <id></id>
            </criteria>
            <operationConfig xsi:type="xsd:Object">
                <dataSource>Brands</dataSource>
                <repo xsi:nil="true"/>
                <operationType>fetch</operationType>
                <textMatchStyle>exact</textMatchStyle>
            </operationConfig>
            <componentId>isc_DynamicForm_0</componentId>
            <appID>builtinApplication</appID>
            <operation>Some_fetch</operation>
            <oldValues xsi:type="xsd:Object">
                <id></id>
            </oldValues>
        </elem>
    </operations>
</transaction>
```

I am using OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer which truncates this data by default. In order to allow this data, I have made following changes to my HTMLPolicyBuilder:

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("br")
    .allowElements("transaction", "transactionNum", "operations", "elem", "criteria", "id", "operationConfig",
          "dataSource", "repo", "operationType", "textMatchStyle", "componentId", "appID", "oldValues","operation")
     .allowAttributes("xmlns:xsi", "xsi:type", "xsi:nil")
     .onElements("transaction", "transactionNum", "operations", "elem", "criteria", "id", 
      "operationConfig", "dataSource", "repo", "operationType", "textMatchStyle", "componentId", "appID", "oldValues")
     .toFactory();
```

When I am sanitizing my XML using this Policy, It changes my data into lowercase for example `transactionNum` becomes `transactionnum`.

Can anyone help me on how to prevent this or how to allow my Policy to skip all tags inside another, for example, allow all tags inside `<transaction>` tag in this case.